# How to add Ubuntu to Arch Linux grub (dual boot) (UEFI)

Tags: arch-linux, grub, uefi, partition-table

I want to have Dual Boot, the problem is that if I install Arch Linux after Ubuntu I don't know how to make that Arch Linux detect Ubuntu.

I partitioned Ubuntu in this way

[image]

In Arch I only create root partition, so the result is this

[image]

Then I did this:

```
 mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda4
 mount /dev/sda4 /mnt
 mkdir /mnt/boot
 mkdir /mnt/boot/EFI
 mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/EFI
```

The result is

[image]

Close to finish the installation I did

```
pacman -S grub efibootmgr
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/EFI --bootloader-id=GRUB
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

But don't Found Ubuntu

Obs: I try making one EFI partition for Ubuntu and other EFI partition for Arch, I did the same process and nothing.

So what I need to do to add Ubuntu to Arch Linux grub. Thx

Comment: Did you install Arch in /dev/sda4  once you made a partition for it?

Comment: If u mean the pacstrap, genfstab etc yes

Answer (score 1):

You've done everything correctly, as far as I can see.

A couple of steps will solve the issue, as root (sudo):

```
# pacman -S os-prober
# os-prober
```

And, that's it.
It's almost easier than Ubuntu; more elegant, certainly.

Comment: That's it what? Does `os-prober` automatically update the grub? It didn't work for me. :/

Answer (score 1):

That problem is likely from the final line of /etc/default/grub
[image: example]
Uncomment the final line, install os-prober if you haven't already, and run `grub-mkconfig -o <grub dir>/grub.cfg` (example command for the default grub directory:`grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`) as root

Answer (score 1):

I just today installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a system with an existing archlinux installation (archlinux was the only OS on the disk).  The Ubuntu installer explicitly gave the option to install dual-boot with archlinux.  I chose that option, and Ubuntu rewrote the grub boot menu to include Ubuntu (as the first of the list :) ) along with entries for the archlinux installation (normal and advanced options).  I tested the archlinux boot from the new menu and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thx for answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same problem (in a VM). The ubuntu partition just had to be mounted before calling os-prober:

```
mkdir ubuntu
mount /dev/vda2 /ubuntu
os-prober
```

(I know the question dates from years ago, but this was the only hint I found to my problem, so I am uploading my solution in case someone else finds this useful in the future)